IRC Bot Not Connecting Through Proxy Server in Python
Introduce the Problem: I'm developing an IRC bot in Python that needs to connect to an IRC server through a proxy server. However, the bot fails to establish a connection.
Expand on the Problem: I am using the following modules: irc, socks, socket.
Terminal Output:
INFO:root:Bot created. Starting...
DEBUG:irc.client:connect(server='irc.libera.chat', port=6667, nickname='uwu', ...)
INFO:root:Successfully set proxy: 178.128.113.118:8000
DEBUG:irc.client:_dispatcher: disconnect
DEBUG:irc.client:process_forever(timeout=0.2)
Proxy: I am using a free proxy obtained from a website.
Expand on the Problem: Here is the relevant part of my code:
import irc.bot
import irc.strings
import irc.connection
import socks
import socket
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class IRCBot(irc.bot.SingleServerIRCBot):
    def __init__(self, channel, nickname, server, port=6667, proxy_type=None, proxy_addr=None, proxy_port=None):
        self.proxy_type = proxy_type
        self.proxy_addr = proxy_addr
        self.proxy_port = proxy_port
        
        if proxy_type:
            connect_factory = irc.connection.Factory(wrapper=self._get_wrapper)
        else:
            connect_factory = irc.connection.Factory()
        
        irc.bot.SingleServerIRCBot.__init__(self, [(server, port)], nickname, nickname, connect_factory=connect_factory)
        self.channel = channel

    def _get_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sock = socks.socksocket()
        if self.proxy_type:
            try:
                sock.set_proxy(self.proxy_type, self.proxy_addr, self.proxy_port)
                logging.info(f"Successfully set proxy: {self.proxy_addr}:{self.proxy_port}")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Failed to set proxy: {e}")
                logging.info("Falling back to direct connection")
                sock = socket.socket()
        return sock

    def on_welcome(self, connection, event):
        logging.info(f"Connected to server. Joining channel {self.channel}")
        connection.join(self.channel)

    def on_join(self, connection, event):
        if event.source.nick == connection.get_nickname():
            logging.info(f"Joined channel {event.target}")
            connection.privmsg(self.channel, "hi guys")

def main():
    channel = "#Anime-18"
    nickname = "uwu"
    server = "irc.libera.chat"  # Using Libera Chat as it's a popular network
    port = 6667

    proxy_type = socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS4
    proxy_addr = "178.128.113.118"
    proxy_port = 8000

    try:
        bot = IRCBot(channel, nickname, server, port, proxy_type, proxy_addr, proxy_port)
        logging.info("Bot created. Starting...")
        bot.start()
    except irc.client.ServerConnectionError as e:
        logging.error(f"Error connecting to server: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


"Proxy: I am using a free proxy obtained from a website." - the proxy you are using does not work as a socks proxy. Don't rely on any arbitrary proxy you'll find somewhere to support the functionality you want.
